# Instant preview color in LyX

Tags: color, lyx, preview

I'm using the instant preview feature in LyX, which as I understand is based on a LaTeX package of the same name. As I have LyX configured with a dark background -

**Is there anyway to configure the instant preview to output a different color (say white)?**

**Edit:**

It appears that LyX is using `dvipng` through `preview.sty` to generate the output, which does have a color option. If I knew where `dvipng` was being called from, perhaps I could add the color flag, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Just to be clear, what exactly is the name of the LaTeX package? It likely comes with documentation.

Comment: @SeanAllred - I think it's: /usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/preview/preview.sty

Comment: Thanks :) For reference, something like `preview` is descriptive enough :) from here, we can look at [CTAN's listing](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/preview).

Comment: If you go to Tools -> Preferences -> File handling -> Converters, you'll find *LyX Preview* in the list. That points to a Python script called `lyxpreview2bitmap.py` that is (I think) in `/usr/share/lyx/scripts/`. I haven't looked too closely at the script yet, but perhaps you can figure it out. (If this is helpful I can add a proper answer.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. - Thank you. Although the script has a color flag, it's not clear where the 6 command line arguments are coming from. If you wish to add an answer, a bounty awaits :)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. - "Forcing" `fg_color` in the script works, but of course this is a bit of a hack. It would be nice to know where `fg_color` is being passed in from, and change it there.

Comment: Oh, it did? I can't get it to work, so I've probably done something wrong. I'll add an answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Under Tools --> Preferences -> File handling -> Converters, there is an entry called *LyX Preview -> PNG*. The converter given for this entry is

```
python -tt $$s/scripts/lyxpreview2bitmap.py
```

`$$s` is a placeholder that, as I understand it, points to the LyX library directory, which can be `/usr/share/lyx/` on a Linux system. Open Help --> About LyX to see the path to that directory.

That script is called with six arguments, though exactly where and how it is called I cannot say, so I don't know how to modify that. As a bad hack you could set `fg_color` (and/or `bg_color`) explicitly to a colour of your choice, in lines 300-301 of `lyxpreview2bitmap.py`, or in the call to `dvipng` (line 372). Not a very good workaround though.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in newer version of `LyX` one can simply change the command under `Tools / Preferences / File handling / Converters / LyX Preview -> PNG`
to:

```
python -tt $$s/scripts/lyxpreview2bitmap.py --png --fg="ccffff"
```

Where in this example `#ccffff` was chosen as the foreground color.

Answer (score 0):

My LyX version is 2.2.1, 
If you check the codes of lyxpreview2bitmap.py,
it has its options:

```
>   --dpi=<res>:   Resolution per inch (default: 128)   --png, --ppm: 
> Select the output format (default: png)   --fg=<color>:  Foreground
> color (default: black, ie '000000')   --bg=<color>:  Background color
> (default: white, ie 'ffffff')   --latex=<exe>: Specify the executable
> for latex (default: latex)   --bibtex=<exe>: Specify the executable
> for bibtex (default: bibtex)   --lilypond:    Preprocess through
> lilypond-book (default: false)   --lilypond-book=<exe>:
>                  The executable for lilypond-book (default: lilypond-book)
> 
>   -d, --debug:   Show the output from external commands   -h, --help: 
> Show this help screen and exit   -v, --verbose: Show progress messages
> 
> The colors are hexadecimal strings, eg 'faf0e6'."""
```

Like @nbubis showed, we can click "modify" button for "LyX Preview -> PNG",
which can be found by searching "lyxpreview2bitmap" in LyX: Preferences.
another example can be:

```
python -tt $$s/scripts/lyxpreview2bitmap.py --png --fg="3f38cf" --bg="faf0e6"
```